# Is it possible to Copy and Paste Texts to/from a stack in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

Ctrl + C can only store a single selected text in clipboard. I need to **Copy Multiple Texts** from different places and paste them to another Places. Is there any Tool(Add-in) for Visual Studio(2010) to handle that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually Visual Studio has a feature called the clipboard ring. Basically, whenever you copy text to the clipboard in Visual Studio, the previously copied text is kept in a history buffer. You can press CTRL+V to paste the text you just copied, or press CTRL+SHIFT+V to cycle through the items you have copied.

So while you can't paste all of the items on the clipboard ring at once, you can copy multiple chunks of text to the clipboard and then paste them one after another.

[Tips and Tricks: Clipboard Ring and Toolbox Snippets](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/10/tips-and-tricks-clipboard-ring-and-toolbox-snippets.aspx)